# HTML Form required fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JS Code:

```
function validateForm() {

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var y=document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
if (y==null || y=="") {
  alert("Password name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
    }
```

and this HTML:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
Name*: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
Password*: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can i make my javascript code work on all forms where input `class="required"`

Comment: Why don't you try using jQuery for accessing elements and adding validation rules?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your html code and it validates before moving onto the PHP page

you had a bug in your form - you forgot to add the form name "myform" so it wasnt getting the values until i added this  because the javascript didnt know where to get the value from and i added a value named "good" which if it is false, everything else is false and it doesnt return values to the php server

Hope this helps

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate_Form() {
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
        var good = new Boolean(true);

        if (x==null || x=="")
          {
          alert("Name must be filled out");
          good = false;
          }

        var y=document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;

        if (y==null || y=="") 
        {
          alert("Password name must be filled out");
          good = false;
        }
          return good
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_Form()">
    Name*: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    Password*: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you. You would need to change name_id and password_id to your id's for those elements. Than you can get the classname and check to see if it equals required.

```
function validateForm() {

var name = document.getElementById('name_id').className;
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
if (name == "required") {
    if (x == null || x == "")
    {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
var password = document.getElementById('password_id').className;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
if (password == "required") {
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Password name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

The way to do it all by class would be something like this:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('required');
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if (x[i].value == null || x[i].value == "")
        {
            alert("Field must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<form>
Name*: <input type="text" name="name" class="required"> <br>
Password*: <input type="password" name="password" class="required"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();return false;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CheckRequired(){
var AllInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < AllInputs.length; i++){
    if (AllInputs[i].getAttribute('class') === 'required' && AllInputs[i].Value = "")
     {
       return false;
       alert('Please fill out all required fields');
     }
  }
}
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return CheckRequired();">
</form>
```

Comment: how can i enable this on every form on my site for when they are submitted?

Comment: is there nothing i can do in the JS code to do it to save me going through all of my forms and adding this to the submit buttons ?

Comment: your latest code isnt working, ive tried and also tried in a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ds9fM/